# Webpack includes in build file unknown code (nothing from my code & node_modules) with arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I have a problem with webpack when transpiling code by babel to generate production build.
This code is showing in build file, but I can't find out from where it comes. For ex. this line: "Expected the arguments to be of type `string`" doesn't exist in my code and node_modules, so probably it comes from webpack engine.

Code from nowhere:

```
e.exports = (e, t) => {
    if ("string" != typeof e || "string" != typeof t) throw new TypeError("Expected the arguments to be of type `string`");
    if ("" === t) return [e];
    const n = e.indexOf(t);
    return -1 === n ? [e] : [e.slice(0, n), e.slice(n + t.length)]
  }
```

I need to remove this code because on IE it doesn't work, because of arrow function inside.

Thanks
Piotrek

I've already tried suggestions from this topics, but doesn't work:
https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle/issues/1023
https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle/issues/998